# Copy multiple sheets in a workbook to a summary sheet based on autofilter criteria

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I have a code that is not working in copying data from multiple sheets into a single one based on autofilter criteria.

I have this code and it is copying the data from different sheets but on applying autofilter condition it stops working

```
Sub CopyDataWithoutHeaders()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim DestSh As Worksheet
Dim Last As Long
Dim shLast As Long
Dim CopyRng As Range
Dim StartRow As Long
Dim WSNew As Worksheet
Dim MyRange As Range
Dim my_range As Range
Dim Rng As Range

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

'Add a worksheet
'Set DestSh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add

Set DestSh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet16")
'DestSh.Name = "Destination"

'Fill in the start row
StartRow = 2

'loop through all worksheets and copy the data to the DestSh
For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If IsError(Application.Match(sh.Name, _
        Array(DestSh.Name, "Format", "Lookups"), 0)) And sh.Visible = True Then
        'Find the last row with data on the DestSh and sh
        Last = LastRow(DestSh)
        shLast = LastRow(sh)
        MsgBox sh.Name

        Set my_range = Range("A1:ZZ" & LastRow(ActiveSheet))
        my_range.Parent.Select

        'If sh is not empty and if the last row >= StartRow copy the CopyRng
        If shLast >= StartRow Then

            my_range.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
            ActiveSheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=22, Criteria1:="=Ready to import"
            'ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1, 0).Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

            With my_range.Parent.AutoFilter.Range

                Set Rng = .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) _
                    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

                    MsgBox my_range

                    If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                        'Copy and paste the cells into DestSh below the existing data
                        Rng.Copy

                        With DestSh.Range("A" & LastRow(DestSh) + 1)
                            .PasteSpecial Paste:=8
                            .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                            .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                             Application.CutCopyMode = False
                         End With
                     End If

'            Intersect(.UsedRange, .UsedRange.Offset(1)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
'            DestSh.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues  

                    MsgBox Last

'        With DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "A")
'        .PasteSpecial Paste:=8
'            .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
'            .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
'             Application.CutCopyMode = False
'            .Select
'        End With
 ' End If

                    'Close AutoFilter
                    my_range.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

                    'Set the range that you want to copy

                    ' Set CopyRng = sh.Range(sh.Rows(StartRow), sh.Rows(shLast))

                    'Test if there enough rows in the DestSh to copy all the data
'                If Last + MyRange.Rows.Count > DestSh.Rows.Count Then
'                   MsgBox "There are not enough rows in the Destsh"
'                    GoTo ExitTheSub
'                End If

                'This example copies values/formats, if you only want to copy the
                'values or want to copy everything look below example 1 on this page
'                CopyRng.Copy
'                With DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "A")
'                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
'                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
'                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End With

        End If

        'End If

'ExitTheSub:
'
'    Application.Goto DestSh.Cells(1)
'
'    'AutoFit the column width in the DestSh sheet
'    DestSh.Columns.AutoFit
'
'    With Application
'        .ScreenUpdating = True
'        .EnableEvents = True
   'End With
End Sub


Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function


Function LastCol(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastCol = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Column
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

The sheets should be copied one below another if they match the criteria.

Comment: Please post all your code correctly, so it can be read.

Comment: do you actually need the `=` in your criteria?

Comment: I have edited it.Now it has started throwing type mismatch error .

Comment: Hi ,
Thank you so much for the help .
It is now throwing Application or object defined error .
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This is basic code does what you are trying to accomplish.

```
Sub CopyDataWithoutHeaders()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, DestSh As Worksheet, Rng As Range
    Set DestSh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet16")

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If ws.Name <> "Format" And ws.Name <> "Lookups" And ws.Name <> DestSh.Name Then

            'the below line will not select the complete range if a cell is empty in column 1
            'it can be changed to the way you want.
            Set Rng = ws.Range("A1", ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))

            With Rng 'will copy all the range except the header row  
                .AutoFilter Field:=22, Criteria1:="Ready to import", Operator:=xlAnd
                .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
            End With

                'test if the first cell is empty before pasting 
                If DestSh.Range("A1") = "" Then
                    DestSh.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

                Else: DestSh.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                End If
        End If

        'clean up each worksheet
        ws.AutoFilterMode = False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Next ws

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help

Issue Solved

Sub CopyDataWithoutHeaders()

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, DestSh As Worksheet, Rng As Range

Set DestSh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("All")

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets

     If ws.Name <> "Format" And ws.Name <> "Lookups" And ws.Name <> DestSh.Name Then

        Set Rng = ws.UsedRange

        With Rng 'will copy all the range except the header row

           .AutoFilter Field:=22, Criteria1:="Ready to import", Operator:=xlAnd

           ***If (ws.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count > 1)*** Then

            .Offset(1, 0).Resize(Rng.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
            DestSh.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

           End If

        End With

    End If

    'clean up each worksheet
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
Next ws

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With
```

End Sub

Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Comment: If you are providing an answer to your own question, you might want to identify how the issue was solved., so others reviewing your question can learn.

Comment: The range was not picking up any value in the definition . the issue was resolved using an if condition that is highlighted within asterix.